# Hibernate Entity Class maps to two different Tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to Map my `@Entity` objects to their respective classes where one is a parameter of the other.

To put it simply I have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableA")
public class ClassA {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String paramA;

    private ClassB classB;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

ClassB looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableB")
public class ClassB {
    @Id
    private long classAId;

    private String paramB;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

To save I am using the Interface - (I suspect this or the way I am using it is my problem?)

```
@Transactional
public interface ClassADao extends JpaRepository<ClassA, Integer> {

}
```

In my DB all parameters in ClassA map to a corresponding table except for ClassB which has parameters that all match to a different table for ClassB. I'm new to Hibernate and was hoping it would map the params of ClassB to the correct table. However it appears to be trying to map ClassB to a column in the table for ClassA and thus giving me this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'classB' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
```

My question is, is there a way (preferably through Annotation) to tell Hibernate to make the params in ClassB map to it's own table? I have tried using @SecondaryTable but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to create a different JpaRepository interface for ClassB and save them separately? I was hoping for a cascading effect but maybe that is not possible?

Comment: Can you give table structure as well, or you let hibernate generate it? From the first look it seams you are missing @OneToOne annotation which tells hibernate that you have relation. You can check http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/ where stock has stock details.

Comment: +1 For providing tables structure. You have not defined any relationship between the entities A and B in your code, so there's no way Hibernate/JPA is going to know map them correctly. You have to do that via JPA annotations (`@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, etc.). You can google for JPA tutorial. About your dao... there's no need to make it `@Transactional` (Spring data will take care of that) and since your id is a long you should extend `JpaRepository<ClassA, Long>`.

Comment: @NenadBozic - The Table structure mimics the Objects. So I would have TableA with columns id, paramA and TableB with paramB.

Comment: @NenadBozic - Yes OneToOne mapping  is what seems to be missing. Doing some more research shows a few ways to do this. I will add soon the way I did it and if you have a better way please put as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from the people who commented on this, I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private ClassB classB;

public setClassB(ClassB classB) {
    this.classB = classB;
    this.classB.setClassA(this);
}
```

And edited ClassB like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableB")
public class ClassB {
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ClassA classA

    private String paramB;

    // getters and setters here - including for ClassA
```

}

Now when I call the Spring injected `ClassADao.save(classA)`, `ClassB` also gets saved in the DB correctly for free.

Comment: Would be happy to know if there is a better solution. This is what I came up with.

Comment: Right now, there's not, though I'm working on a toolkit to automate most of this if using Groovy is an option. https://blog.chrylis.com